# How to run groovy based JUnit Test Suite from the command line?

Tags: selenium, groovy, junit, spock, geb

How to run the JUnit test suite containing a set of test cases(groovy based) from the command line. Following is the test suite class generated by eclipse.

```
package com.example.testclasses;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ abc.class, xyz.class })
public class AllTests {

}
```

The above test suite works when I run the above test suite(AllTests)as JUnit from eclipse, however, I want to run the test suite(AllTests) from the command line. How do I do this?
Info: I am using Geb(Groovy) based testing where all the test cases(example: abc, def) are groovy based(having .groovy extension).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
java -cp /path/to/groovy/embeddable/groovy-all-1.8.1.jar groovy.lang.GroovyShell AllTests.groovy
```

where `1.8.1` should be replaced with your version of `groovy-all-*.jar`

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to run your tests from the command line I would suggest using a build system. My personal choice would be to use Gradle but you could probably also get away with using Maven.

The benefit of using a build system, apart from being able to run the tests from the command line, is that it will help you manage your dependencies and it will be easier to build the project for others working on the same codebase - they won't have to manually setup all the dependencies and their versions in the IDE.